# Touchpad becoming unresponsive

Tags: mouse, touchpad

After a few days, my laptop's touchpad stops responding. Rebooting fixes it, but is there any way to reload whatever driver or kernel module manages that, so I don't have to re-setup my environment each time?

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 on a Dell Precision 5520, that came pre-installed with Ubuntu.

My output for `/sbin/lsmod` is:

```
Module                  Size  Used by
dm_crypt               28672  0
algif_skcipher         20480  0
af_alg                 16384  1 algif_skcipher
pci_stub               16384  1
vboxpci                24576  0
vboxnetadp             28672  0
vboxnetflt             28672  0
vboxdrv               458752  3 vboxnetadp,vboxnetflt,vboxpci
nls_utf8               16384  0
isofs                  40960  0
vhost_net              20480  1
vhost                  36864  1 vhost_net
macvtap                20480  1 vhost_net
macvlan                24576  1 macvtap
ip6t_REJECT            16384  2
nf_reject_ipv6         16384  1 ip6t_REJECT
xt_CHECKSUM            16384  2
iptable_mangle         16384  1
ipt_MASQUERADE         16384  6
nf_nat_masquerade_ipv4    16384  1 ipt_MASQUERADE
iptable_nat            16384  1
nf_nat_ipv4            16384  1 iptable_nat
nf_nat                 28672  2 nf_nat_ipv4,nf_nat_masquerade_ipv4
nf_conntrack_ipv4      20480  3
nf_defrag_ipv4         16384  1 nf_conntrack_ipv4
xt_conntrack           16384  2
nf_conntrack          106496  5 nf_nat,nf_nat_ipv4,xt_conntrack,nf_nat_masquerade_ipv4,nf_conntrack_ipv4
ipt_REJECT             16384  4
nf_reject_ipv4         16384  1 ipt_REJECT
xt_tcpudp              16384  12
bridge                126976  0
stp                    16384  1 bridge
llc                    16384  2 stp,bridge
ebtable_filter         16384  0
ebtables               32768  1 ebtable_filter
ip6table_filter        16384  1
ip6_tables             28672  1 ip6table_filter
iptable_filter         16384  1
ip_tables              24576  3 iptable_filter,iptable_mangle,iptable_nat
x_tables               36864  12 ip6table_filter,xt_CHECKSUM,ip_tables,xt_tcpudp,ipt_MASQUERADE,xt_conntrack,iptable_filter,ebtables,ipt_REJECT,iptable_mangle,ip6_tables,ip6t_REJECT
kvm_intel             172032  4
nfnetlink_queue        20480  0
nfnetlink_log          20480  0
nfnetlink              16384  2 nfnetlink_log,nfnetlink_queue
cdc_acm                36864  0
uas                    24576  0
usb_storage            69632  1 uas
cdc_ether              16384  0
usbnet                 45056  1 cdc_ether
r8152                  49152  0
mii                    16384  2 r8152,usbnet
hid_apple              16384  0
hid_generic            16384  0
usbhid                 49152  0
drbg                   32768  1
ansi_cprng             16384  0
ctr                    16384  3
ccm                    20480  3
rfcomm                 69632  2
arc4                   16384  2
bnep                   20480  2
usblp                  20480  0
hid_multitouch         20480  0
binfmt_misc            20480  1
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     49152  1
i2c_designware_platform    16384  0
i2c_designware_core    20480  1 i2c_designware_platform
dell_wmi               16384  0
dell_rbtn              16384  0
dell_led               16384  1
snd_hda_codec_realtek   106496  1
snd_hda_codec_generic    73728  1 snd_hda_codec_realtek
dell_laptop            20480  0
dcdbas                 16384  1 dell_laptop
intel_rapl             20480  0
dell_smm_hwmon         16384  0
x86_pkg_temp_thermal    16384  0
intel_powerclamp       16384  0
coretemp               16384  0
kvm                   548864  1 kvm_intel
irqbypass              16384  3 kvm
crct10dif_pclmul       16384  0
crc32_pclmul           16384  0
snd_hda_intel          40960  6
snd_hda_codec         139264  4 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_intel
ghash_clmulni_intel    16384  0
aesni_intel           167936  6
snd_hda_core           90112  5 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel
snd_hwdep              16384  1 snd_hda_codec
aes_x86_64             20480  1 aesni_intel
lrw                    16384  1 aesni_intel
ath10k_pci             45056  0
gf128mul               16384  1 lrw
glue_helper            16384  1 aesni_intel
snd_pcm               106496  6 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_core
ablk_helper            16384  1 aesni_intel
ath10k_core           315392  1 ath10k_pci
cryptd                 20480  3 ghash_clmulni_intel,aesni_intel,ablk_helper
snd_seq_midi           16384  0
snd_seq_midi_event     16384  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_rawmidi            32768  1 snd_seq_midi
ath                    32768  1 ath10k_core
joydev                 20480  0
snd_seq                69632  2 snd_seq_midi_event,snd_seq_midi
input_leds             16384  0
mac80211              737280  1 ath10k_core
snd_seq_device         16384  3 snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq_midi
serio_raw              16384  0
snd_timer              32768  2 snd_pcm,snd_seq
snd                    81920  21 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hwdep,snd_timer,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_pcm,snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_seq_device
uvcvideo               90112  0
videobuf2_vmalloc      16384  1 uvcvideo
soundcore              16384  1 snd
idma64                 20480  0
videobuf2_memops       16384  1 videobuf2_vmalloc
virt_dma               16384  1 idma64
videobuf2_v4l2         28672  1 uvcvideo
videobuf2_core         36864  2 uvcvideo,videobuf2_v4l2
cfg80211              565248  3 ath,mac80211,ath10k_core
v4l2_common            16384  1 videobuf2_v4l2
btusb                  45056  0
btrtl                  16384  1 btusb
btbcm                  16384  1 btusb
videodev              180224  4 uvcvideo,v4l2_common,videobuf2_core,videobuf2_v4l2
btintel                16384  1 btusb
rtsx_pci_ms            20480  0
media                  24576  2 uvcvideo,videodev
bluetooth             520192  29 bnep,btbcm,btrtl,btusb,rfcomm,btintel
memstick               20480  1 rtsx_pci_ms
intel_lpss_pci         16384  0
intel_lpss             16384  1 intel_lpss_pci
mei_me                 36864  0
shpchp                 36864  0
mei                    98304  1 mei_me
processor_thermal_device    16384  0
intel_soc_dts_iosf     16384  1 processor_thermal_device
intel_hid              16384  0
mac_hid                16384  0
sparse_keymap          16384  2 dell_wmi,intel_hid
acpi_pad               24576  0
int3403_thermal        16384  0
int340x_thermal_zone    16384  2 processor_thermal_device,int3403_thermal
int3400_thermal        16384  0
acpi_thermal_rel       16384  1 int3400_thermal
sunrpc                335872  1
parport_pc             32768  0
ppdev                  20480  0
lp                     20480  0
parport                49152  3 lp,ppdev,parport_pc
autofs4                40960  2
rtsx_pci_sdmmc         24576  0
i915_bpo             1335296  7
intel_ips              20480  1 i915_bpo
i2c_algo_bit           16384  1 i915_bpo
drm_kms_helper        155648  1 i915_bpo
psmouse               131072  0
syscopyarea            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
sysfillrect            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
sysimgblt              16384  1 drm_kms_helper
fb_sys_fops            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
drm                   364544  8 i915_bpo,drm_kms_helper
nvme                   69632  4
rtsx_pci               53248  2 rtsx_pci_ms,rtsx_pci_sdmmc
ahci                   36864  0
libahci                32768  1 ahci
wmi                    20480  2 dell_led,dell_wmi
i2c_hid                20480  0
hid                   122880  5 i2c_hid,hid_multitouch,hid_generic,usbhid,hid_apple
video                  40960  3 i915_bpo,dell_wmi,dell_laptop
fjes                   28672  0
```

Comment: What make/model of laptop? Are you running Ubuntu? Which release? use `/sbin/lsmod` to see which modules are loaded.

Comment: @waltinator I've updated my post.

Answer (score 0):

I'd guess the module you want is `hid_multitouch` ("`hid`", or rathe "HID", stands for "Human Interface Device".

```
$ modinfo hid_multitouch
filename:       /lib/modules/4.15.0-34-generic/kernel/drivers/hid/hid-multitouch.ko
license:        GPL
description:    HID multitouch panels
author:         Benjamin Tissoires <benjamin.tissoires@gmail.com>
author:         Stephane Chatty <chatty@enac.fr>
srcversion:     F120069FA6914E49C917A88
alias:          hid:b*g0004v*p*
alias:          hid:b*g0002v*p*
alias:          hid:b*g*v000018D1p00005028
alias:          hid:b0003g0002v00001477p00001025
alias:          hid:b0003g0002v00001477p00001026
alias:          hid:b0003g0002v00001477p00001024
alias:          hid:b0003g0002v00001477p00001022
alias:          hid:b0003g0002v00001477p00001023
alias:          hid:b0003g0002v00001477p00001021
alias:          hid:b0003g0002v00001477p0000100E
alias:          hid:b0003g0002v00001477p00001007
alias:          hid:b0003g0002v00001477p00001006
alias:          hid:b0003g0002v00002505p00000220
alias:          hid:b0003g0002v00000FB8p00001109
alias:          hid:b0003g0002v00000306p0000FF3F
alias:          hid:b0003g0002v0000227Dp00000A19
alias:          hid:b0003g0002v0000227Dp00000709
alias:          hid:b0003g0002v00001E5Ep00000313
alias:          hid:b0003g0002v00001784p00000016
alias:          hid:b0003g0002v00000483p00003261
alias:          hid:b0003g0002v00000408p00003001
alias:          hid:b0003g0002v00002087p00000703
alias:          hid:b0003g0002v0000093Ap00008003
alias:          hid:b0003g0002v0000093Ap00008002
alias:          hid:b0003g0002v0000093Ap00008001
alias:          hid:b0018g0004v00001B96p00001B05
alias:          hid:b0003g0002v00000603p00000600
alias:          hid:b0003g0002v000004DAp0000104D
alias:          hid:b0003g0002v000004DAp00001044
alias:          hid:b0003g0002v0000062Ap00007100
alias:          hid:b0003g0002v00000486p00000186
alias:          hid:b0003g0002v00000486p00000185
alias:          hid:b0003g*v00001FD2p00006007
alias:          hid:b0003g0002v0000222Ap00000001
alias:          hid:b0003g0002v000022EDp00001010
alias:          hid:b0003g0002v00001AADp0000000F
alias:          hid:b0005g0002v000025B6p00000002
alias:          hid:b0003g0002v00000DFCp0000E100
alias:          hid:b0003g0002v00000DFCp0000010A
alias:          hid:b0003g0002v00000DFCp00000106
alias:          hid:b0003g0002v00000DFCp00000102
alias:          hid:b0003g0002v00000DFCp00000101
alias:          hid:b0003g0002v00000DFCp00000100
alias:          hid:b0003g0002v00000DFCp00000003
alias:          hid:b0003g0002v000010C4p000081B9
alias:          hid:b0003g0002v000025B5p00000002
alias:          hid:b0003g0002v000003FCp000005D8
alias:          hid:b0003g0002v00000EEFp0000A001
alias:          hid:b0003g0002v00000EEFp000073F7
alias:          hid:b0003g0002v00000EEFp00007349
alias:          hid:b0003g0002v00000EEFp00007302
alias:          hid:b0003g0002v00000EEFp000072FA
alias:          hid:b0003g*v00000EEFp000072D0
alias:          hid:b0003g*v00000EEFp000072C4
alias:          hid:b0003g0002v00000EEFp000072AA
alias:          hid:b0003g0002v00000EEFp000072A1
alias:          hid:b0003g0002v00000EEFp0000726B
alias:          hid:b0003g0002v00000EEFp00007262
alias:          hid:b0003g0002v00000EEFp0000725E
alias:          hid:b0003g0002v00000EEFp0000722A
alias:          hid:b0003g0002v00000EEFp00007224
alias:          hid:b0003g0002v00000EEFp0000720C
alias:          hid:b0003g0002v00000EEFp00007207
alias:          hid:b0003g0002v00000EEFp0000480E
alias:          hid:b0003g0002v00000EEFp0000480D
alias:          hid:b0003g0002v00001FF7p00000013
alias:          hid:b0003g0002v000024B8p00000040
alias:          hid:b0003g0002v000024B8p00000020
alias:          hid:b0003g0002v00002247p00000001
alias:          hid:b0003g0002v00002087p00000F01
alias:          hid:b0003g0002v00002087p00000A01
alias:          hid:b0003g0002v00002453p00000100
alias:          hid:b0003g0002v000003EBp00002118
alias:          hid:b0003g0004v00000B05p0000184A
alias:          hid:b0003g0002v00001130p00003101
alias:          hid:b0003g0004v000017EFp000060A3
alias:          hid:b0018g0004v0000044Ep0000120A
alias:          hid:b0018g0004v0000044Ep00001220
alias:          hid:b0018g0004v0000044Ep0000121F
alias:          hid:b0003g0002v00000596p00000506
alias:          hid:b0003g0002v00000596p00000502
alias:          hid:b0003g0002v00000596p00000500
depends:        hid
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           hid_multitouch
vermagic:       4.15.0-34-generic SMP mod_unload
```

Comment: I tried `sudo modprobe -r hid_multitouch; sudo modprobe hid_multitouch` but that had no effect.